# Wrong view html rendering

Tags: html, codeigniter, dom

I have this view with codeigniter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/css2/bootstrap.css"/>
<title>example</title>
</head> 
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Merc_inicio extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('plantilla');
    }
}   

?>
```

So in IE8 and Firefox the renderization is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <link href="http://10.66.130.131/mercurio_p/assets/bootstrap/css2/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<title>
      example
</title>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why head tags is beig renderized inside body tags?
I don't know what is happening. Do you?

Comment: Is that your question? I don't clearly see a problem. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i am not a php programmer, but i can tell that your href is getting calculated and displayed accordingly

Comment: The question is: why head tags is beig renderized inside body tags?

Comment: Its because the link isn't closed

Comment: Ok, i just did it, but don't works. And look at the doctype tag. Where is it after rendering?

Comment: What if you add an empty link tag? What comes out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must save files as utf-8 without BOM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you elaborate a little more on why you think this will solve xgrager's problem?  This is very minimal information, and I have to admit that I don't how this will help.

Comment: Awesome! this fix my issue. Thanks a lot. Here some explanations about the difference between utf with and without bom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Merc_inicio extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    }
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('plantilla');
}
}   

?>
```

Comment: I have the url helper in the autoload.php. Thanks.